# Cryptography with Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, caesar-cipher, ordereddictionary

I have been working on Cryptography Question. What I tried to write first code with OrderedDict is this.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

alphabet = OrderedDict(
    [(u'a', u'ç'), (u'b', u'd'), (u'c', u'e'), (u'ç', u'f'), (u'd', u'g'), (u'e', u'g'), (u'f', u'h'),
     (u'g', u'i'), (u'g', u'i'), (u'h', u'j'), (u'i', u'k'), (u'i', u'l'), (u'j', u'm'), (u'k', u'n'),
     (u'l', u'o'), (u'm', u'ö'), (u'n', u'p'), (u'o', u'r'), (u'ö', u's'), (u'p', u'ş'), (u'r', u't'),
     (u's', u'u'), (u'ş', u'ü'), (u't', u'v'), (u'u', u'y'), (u'ü', u'z'), (u'v', u'a'),
     (u'y', u'b'), (u'z',u'c'), (9, '')])


text = 'öğtjçdç9dğp9grnvrt9jyuğbkp9içokoğr9pyp9nçtkbğt9iypoğtk9gycğpoğgkikpk9gybgyö9ağ9uğpkp9kekp9drboğ9dkt9urty9\
            jçcktoçgkö9içokoğr9gç9uvçmç9dçuoçöçn9kekp9vğn9bçşöçp9iğtğnğp9\
                çpçjvçtk9dyogyiyp9ağ9dy9öğvkp9grubçukpk9rnybçdkogkikp9\
                    çoirtkvöçoçtk9kuvğgkikp9gkogğ9nrgoçöçp9ağ9dçuoçtkpç9çpçjvçt9\
                        ağ9ngvççmnçç9bçcçtçn9nrgoçtkpk9uktnğvkp9kphr9çgğtğukpğ9öçko9çvöçpgkt9\jçgk9irtğbkö9uğpk'

out = []

for k, v in alphabet.items():
    for i in list(text):
        if i == v:
            out.append(alphabet[v])

outlast = (''.join(out))

print(outlast)
```

I can't compare list of 'text' and alphabet values. I want to "text's every element(i) compare values and if it be 'i==values' Append i to 'out' list but as keys!" I'm using PyCharm 2017.2.2 Can you Help Me?

Actually Cryptyography Key is 3. "3 times go up on Turkish alphabet"

This is WRONG Output:

```
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffgggggggggggiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiijllllllllllmmmmmmööpppppppppppprrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrsssssssssssşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşştttttttttttttüvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvyyyyyyyyyyyyaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbççççdddddddddeee
```

Expected Output:

```
merhaba ben doktor huseyin galileo nun kariyer gunleri duzenledigini duydum ve senin icin boyle bir soru hazirladim galileo da staja baslamak icin tek yapman gereken anahtari buldugun ve bu metin dosyasini okuyabildigin algoritmalari istedigin dilde kodlaman ve baslarina anahtar ve kdtaajkaa yazarak kodlarini sirketin info aderesine mail atmandir hadi goreyim seni
```

Comment: You spelled alphabet wrong here: for k, v in alfphabet.items():

Comment: Variables were Turkish, I did mistake when I was translating English. So, It's still don't work.

Comment: Don't you need to use variable `k` as well? Programming is expressing your ideas *very* precisely and executing compilation and code in your head.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need OrderedDict, list of tuples works well. Here is how your code may look.

```
alphabet = [(u'a', u'ç'), (u'b', u'd'), (u'c', u'e'), (u'ç', u'f'), (u'd', u'g'), (u'e', u'g'), (u'f', u'h'),
     (u'g', u'i'), (u'g', u'i'), (u'h', u'j'), (u'i', u'k'), (u'i', u'l'), (u'j', u'm'), (u'k', u'n'),
     (u'l', u'o'), (u'm', u'ö'), (u'n', u'p'), (u'o', u'r'), (u'ö', u's'), (u'p', u'ş'), (u'r', u't'),
     (u's', u'u'), (u'ş', u'ü'), (u't', u'v'), (u'u', u'y'), (u'ü', u'z'), (u'v', u'a'),
     (u'y', u'b'), (u'z',u'c'), 
(' ', '9')]    #'9' should be quoted and be the second element of the tuple

text = 'öğtjçdç9dğp9grnvrt9jyuğbkp9içokoğr9pyp9nçtkbğt9iypoğtk9gycğpoğgkikpk9gybgyö9ağ9uğpkp9kekp9drboğ9dkt9urty9\
            jçcktoçgkö9içokoğr9gç9uvçmç9dçuoçöçn9kekp9vğn9bçşöçp9iğtğnğp9\
                çpçjvçtk9dyogyiyp9ağ9dy9öğvkp9grubçukpk9rnybçdkogkikp9\
                    çoirtkvöçoçtk9kuvğgkikp9gkogğ9nrgoçöçp9ağ9dçuoçtkpç9çpçjvçt9\
                        ağ9ngvççmnçç9bçcçtçn9nrgoçtkpk9uktnğvkp9kphr9çgğtğukpğ9öçko9çvöçpgkt9\jçgk9irtğbkö9uğpk'

out = []

for t in list(text): #outer loop is over the text 
    for v in alphabet:  #and inner loop is to search char in the alphabet
        if t == v[1]:
            out += v[0]

outlast = (''.join(out))
print(outlast)
```

Output.

```
mrhaba bn deoktor husyin ggalilo nun kariyr ggunlri deuznldeiggini deuydeum v snin icin boyl bir soru hazirladeim ggalilo dea staja baslamak icin tk yapman ggrkn anahtari buldeuggun v bu mtin deosyasini okuyabildeiggin alggoritmalari istdeiggin deilde kodelaman v baslarina anahtar v kdetaajkaa yazarak kodelarini sirktin info adersin mail atmandeir hadei ggoryim sni
```

There are still some errors in your `alphabet` definition, I leave fixing them to you.